# Dynamic encoding of continuous variables in R data.table

Tags: r, for-loop, dynamic, encoding, data.table

I've got a data.table DT with two variables start and end, which i would like to encode using a dynamic vector. start and end are both some sort of continuous or ordinal variables (integers in this example for ease of use). the dynamic vector contains a dynamically selected  data points in the space of start and end. I'd like to encode the data.table based on the vector.

```
> DT <- data.table(cust = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C')
                 , start = c(1,6,2,2)
                 , end = c(4,8,5,10))
> DT
   cust start end
1:    A     1   4
2:    A     6   8
3:    B     2   5
4:    C     2  10

> dynamic_vector <- c(2,5,7,11)
```

each added column is based on the elements of the dynamic vector. the value of the column start_dynamic_vector[i] is 1 if start <= dynamic_vector[i] and dynamic_vector[i] <= end.

I can do this using a for loop:

```
> for (i in dynamic_vector) DT[, (paste0('month_', i)) := (i >= start & end >= i) + 0L]
> DT
   cust start end month_2 month_5 month_7 month_11
1:    A     1   4       1       0       0        0
2:    A     6   8       0       0       1        0
3:    B     2   5       1       1       0        0
4:    C     2  10       1       1       1        0
```

how can I do this without using a for-loop? I'm dealing with two continuous variables start and end. the dynamic vector can be rather large (a few hundred elements). DT is also a relatively large table (about 50M entries). for-loop takes long!

Comment: Does the functionality of `sapply` satisfy your condition for a non-for loop method?

Comment: if it's faster than for loop, then yes

Comment: just out of curiosity, will `DT[, paste0('m', dynamic_vector) := 0L]; for (i in dynamic_vector) DT[i >= start & end >= i, paste0('m', i) := 1L]` be faster? the fastest most likely will be a `Rcpp` version.

Comment: looks like they take the same mount of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%between%` and `Map`, then assign `:=` all the output variables at once:

```
DT[
  ,
  paste0("month_", dynamic_vector) := lapply(
    Map(`%between%`, dynamic_vector, .(.(start,end))), as.integer
  )
]

#   cust start end month_2 month_5 month_7 month_11
#1:    A     1   4       1       0       0        0
#2:    A     6   8       0       0       1        0
#3:    B     2   5       1       1       0        0
#4:    C     2  10       1       1       1        0
```

Comment: this seems smooth. on a smaller test set this takes 19% less time. I'll wait to see if any other solutions provide further improvement on performance. many thanks.

Comment: There is also `between` function, thus quoting `%between%` might not be necessary. And this function is vectorized, so eventually `Map` might not be required , but I am not sure as I haven't got into this Q well.